# How to make a btrfs snapshot writable?

Tags: linux, btrfs

According to the [btrfs Readonly snapshots patch](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.btrfs/7819) it's possible to "set a snapshot readonly/writable on the fly." So I should be able to turn my readonly snapshot (created with `btrfs snapshot -r`) writable, somehow.

But neither the [btrfs subvolume manpage](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume) nor any other part of that manpage seems to give a way to do that.

Comment: As a workaround you could make a writeble shapshot of your readonly snapshot. (I do this if I don't have the Internet to look up this question)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The btrfs manpage fails to document the `property` subcommand, which I found by grep'ing the source. It's also in `btrfs --help`.

To set a snapshot to read-write, you do something like this:

```
btrfs property set -ts /path/to/snapshot ro false
```

Change that to `true` to set it to read-only.

You can also use `list` to see the available properties:

```
btrfs property list -ts /path/to/snapshot
ro                  Set/get read-only flag of subvolume.
```

`-t` specifies the type of object to work on, `s` means subvolume. Other options are `f` (filesystem), `i` (inode), and `d` (device). If you don't specify, it'll show all applicable ones (for list) or try to guess for get/set.

Edit: in the newest btrfs tools, there is a `btrfs-property` manpage documenting that subcommand, although it's not mentioned in the main manpage at all. It's also available as the [btrfs-property page on the wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property).

(Note: This requires a new-enough btrfs-tools. Apparently on Debian Wheezy, you'll have to install the updated one from wheezy-backports; thanks [artfulrobot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/23542/artfulrobot)).

Comment: You'll also find that while the kernel APIs evolve and distributions ship with newer and newer kernels, the `btrfs-tools` found on some same distributions are not always aligned. So you sometimes found yourself having to compile the latest btrfs-tools form the upstreams git repository to be able to use the btrfs features of your kernel (at least that was very much the case a few years ago).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, definitely. Though in this case I'm on Debian testing, which has btrfs-tools 3.14, so not that insanely old.

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed, it appears 3.14.2 split them out. I have 3.14.1, which is only a few months older, according to [kernel.org git](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/mason/btrfs-progs.git/refs/). But even the [current man page](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/mason/btrfs-progs.git/plain/Documentation/btrfs.txt) doesn't mention properties. I checked (and linked to) the current one on the wiki, too. Turns out the is a [separate, not-linked manpage](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-property) for it though.

Comment: this location of the wiki has changed: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btrfs-property.html