# Is there a simple way to move btrfs subvolumes to a different btrfs filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

I have two separate btrfs filesystems which I would like to consolidate. The subvolume structure looks like this:

```
/ filesystemA
|- subvolume1
|- subvolume2
|- ...
|- subvolumeN

/ filesystemB
|- subvolume1
|- subvolume2
|- ...
|- subvolumeM
```

`filesystemB` is the target. I would like to move subvolumes 1 to N into `filesystemB`. `N` is more than 1000, as they are daily-snapshot subvolumes - also because of this the differences between them are minimal, i.e. there is a lot of shared data. `filesystemA` is 1TB, but a naive `du` on the path totals more than 300TB of files (actual space usage on the drive is less than 500GB).

Therefore I believe a straight `mv` or `cp` from `filesystemA` to `filesystemB` is infeasible, as it won't be aware of btrfs subvolumes or the shared nature of the data.

I've read the documentation on `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive` a couple of times and it looks like this might work, essentially rebuilding the whole subvolume structure on `filesystemB` incrementally. But I'm hoping there is a simpler way, as I'd have to script this (due to the large number of subvolumes) and I feel this may be error-prone.

(Additionally, send/receive requires the subvolumes to be read-only, and the version of btrfs-tools on Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't seem to have the `btrfs property` command that would allow me to set an existing subvolume to read-only. I could install a later version but would prefer not to for the sake of configuration management on this "production" machine.)

Comment: `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive` can be put into a simple script which should do the job.  I did this last year for a few hundred subvolumes (daily/weekly snapshots of ~10 live subvolumes)

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure, you won't get around btrfs-send/btrfs-receive.
Another option would be, to copy the subvolumes and then deduplicate them on the destination, but this would take ages.

For the readonly problem: as these are daily snapshots, arent most of the volumes read-only anyway?

I would do a

```
$btrfs subvolume create /subvolumeA/source
$for i in /filesystemA/subvolume*; do btrfs subvolume snapshot -r $i /filesystemA/source/$i; done
```

Now you have all subvolumes under /filesystemA/source/ readonly.

Now you could send them in a loop incrementaly with btrfs-send with the parent statement to the destination.

If some of the snapshots should be writeable again, you can copy the content of these to a new writeable subvolume using `cp --reflink`.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you got somewhere with your list. Are you sure the `property` commands aren't undocumented on that version? [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149933/161288) suggests you can use a command like `btrfs property set -ts /path/to/snapshot ro true` to correct the issue.

For future readers: Set new snapshots to read-only, with the `-r` parameter when you create them. I'm using something like this in my script:

```
comm -23 \
    <(btrfs subvolume list -ors --sort=path /fsA/ | perl -ne 'print if s/.+?\spath\s+(.+)/\1/') \
    <(btrfs subvolume list -ors --sort=path /fsB/ | perl -ne 'print if s/.+?\spath\s+(.+)/\1/')
```

This should provide a list of read-only snapshot volumes on file-system *A* which are **not** on file-system *B*.
You can iterate the list, doing send/receive on each one to synchronise.